# Mocking C# Func Delegate

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have a question, I have a dependency that is resolved using the Func delegate, how can I use moq in this scenario?

```
 public Func<string, IMylogic> MyLogic { get; set; }
```

The definition is this:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {           
        builder.Services.AddTransient(Factory);
    }

    private static Func<IServiceProvider, Func<string, IMyLogic>> Factory =>
    service =>
    {
        return key =>
        {
            return new MyLogic(key, new System.Net.Http.HttpClient());
        };
    };
}
```

This is just an idea on how the test should work:

```
public class ExecuteEmitLogicTest
{
    ExecuteTransactionCommand ExecuteEmitCommand;
    Dictionary<string, StringValues> queryString;
    Mock<Func<string, IMyLogic>> Concrete;
       
    [Fact]
    public async Task ExecuteEmit()
    { 
        var Concrete = mockFactory.Create<Func<string, IMyLogic>>(MockBehavior.Loose);
        Concrete.Setup(c => c.Invoke(ConcreteTInfo).Execute(request, Guid.Parse(sessionId))).Returns(Task.FromResult(pol));
        ExecuteEmitCommand = new ExecuteTransactionCommand(Concrete.Object);
        var response = await ExecuteEmitCommand.ExecuteAndEmit(queryString, ConcreteTInfo.ApiSkrUrl, ConcreteTInfo.SkrKey, FIXED_HASH);
        Assert.True(response.IsValid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use moq here?  Delegates like this are naturally pluggable without a framework.   Also, I'm unsure why you included the `Startup` class.  What exactly are you trying to mock and test?

Comment: @KirkWoll you are right now that you mentioned it, I should refactor the code. This is a ASP.NET API so I was registering the delegate as a dependency. The code I was trying to test use the delegate as a dependency this way: public Func<string, IMylogic> MyLogic { get; set; } I just added an example of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the redirection part with the <string, interface> function, but I would imagine the test to look more like this:

```
public interface IMyLogic { int GetX(); }
...

Mock<IMyLogic> mockLogic = new Mock<IMyLogic>(MockBehavior.Strict);
// For the unit test always return the mock as 
// we are *not* testing the IMyLogic provider function
Func<string, IMyLogic> f = (string _) => mockLogic.Object;

mockLogic.Setup(ml => ml.GetX()).Returns(7);

var tested = new ExecuteTransactionCommand(f);
var response = await tested.ExecuteAndEmit(queryString, ConcreteTInfo.ApiSkrUrl, ConcreteTInfo.SkrKey, FIXED_HASH);
// Asserts here
```